# Fixing a column width in Zurb Foundation 3?

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a layout where one of my columns holds an ad.  See image 1:

[image: image1]

The ad image is in a four-column div. The ad is an MREC which is 300px wide.  However, on the iPad, since the columns reduce, the ad goes down to 236px which is a no-no.  See image 2 below, of course it looks the same here but it is smaller:

[image: image2]

I need it to stay at 300px. Also, sometimes the ad server may serve an iframe-based ad (also 300px).

So that div needs to not shrink width.

I tried adding a class to that did and setting css to min-width:300px, but then on the iPad it sticks out the right edge; the other div does not shrink accordingly enough. See image 3:

[image: image3]

So, how do I ensure the divs with my ads are not re-sized on the iPad?

EDIT:  Also, the problem seems compounded when I reverse the column order with push-pull.  I am doing this since I need the ad to come first on the phone but second on other platforms:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="four columns ad push-eight">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="eight columns pull-four">
  <h1>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tri-tip shankle chicken leberkas beef pork</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want responsive design or not? If you do, you'll have to let image resize or consider different layout for tablets (Foundation should provide a great base for that).

Comment: I want responsive design, but the contract for the ads requires we do not mess with the ad size.  Hence my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get this to work, I had to step outside of Foundation a bit. Here's what you'll need.

Example: http://cdpn.io/Kypen

Explained:
I created an ad wrapper `.ad` and a `.container` element.

The `.ad` is 300px wide and floated to the right; while the `.container` element is given a 320px wide margin. Since Foundation is using border-box sizing the margin is factored in to the width of the overall `.container` element. As a result, the `.ad` sits inside the "false margin" (the 20 extra px is for white space). This is an old trick and it works inside Foundation's .row & .column elements just fine, in addition it doesn't affect nested rows from being created either.

I also added a media query, use can use this to change the behavior at low resolution.

```
.ad
{
  float:right;
  width:300px;
}
.container
{
  position:relative;
  margin-right:320px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
  {
  .ad
  {float:none;}
  .container
  {margin:0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to fix the width of my sidebar I ended up doing it with calc(). I wanted to have my sidebar below the main content on smaller devices and this way it was really easy.

My layout in haml

```
.row
  .content.column.large-9
    = yield
  .sidebar.column.large-3
    = render 'sidebar'
```

Styles

```
.sidebar{
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
}
@media #{$small} {
  .sidebar {
    width: 225px !important;
  }
  .content {
    width: 70.2% !important; /* Fallback for older browsers */
    width: calc(100% - 240px) !important;
  }
}
```

The media query parameter $small is really confusing as it actually means "larger than small".